# How to extract the user name from ctx.CurrentItem.Author?

Tags: 2013, javascript, jslink

I'm customizing the `DisplayForm` with `jslink` and like to know how to treat the field `Author` and extract some informations.

For example, the object `ctx.CurrentItem.Author` returns me this string:

```
10;#Carlos Amaral,#i:0#.f|membership|cebamara@email.com.br,#Carlos.Amaral@email.com.br,#car‌​los.amaral@email.com.br,#Carlos Amaral
```

How extract the name, id and e-mail from this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author (Created By) is an array in a View and (*I didn't know either*) a String on the Forms

To return a single Author:

```
  function userInfo(ctx){
    var author=ctx.CurrentItem.Author;
    if(typeof author==='string'){
      author=author.split('#');//split string to array
      author={'id':author[0]
              ,'title':author[1]
              ,'sip':author[3]
              ,'email':author[4]
             }
    }else{
        author=author[0];//single author on a View page
    }
    return(author);
  }
```

Comment: This returns me parts of string, ie `ctx.ListData.Items[0].Author[2]` give me `;`. The Sharepoint hasn't any function to turn this in a object?

Comment: There is only one person in the Author **array** You need: ``ctx.CurrentItem.Author[0].email``

Comment: The Author field come to me like **string**, [look this print](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F0HuM.png).

Comment: `ctx` in global mode is `undefined`. I'm using Sharepoint Online 2013.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32058/discussion-between-danny-engelman-and-carlos).

Answer (score 0):

Person or Group field
The base characteristics of a person or group field is the same as a lookup field. The lookup list is the user information list in each site collection.
The field values in JSLink will be returned as an array too. The array elements contain some relevant properties of the user and group. The script below lists all the available properties.

```
 // Requesting values of a person or group field named ‘Person’
    // returns an array of elements
    var users = ctx.CurrentItem[“Person”];

    for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){

        // access department information of user or group
        var curUserDepartment = users[i].department;

        // access email address of user or group
        var curUserEmail = users[i].email;

        // access id of user or group
       // can be used to query user information list
       var curUserId = users[i].id;

       // access job title of user or group
       var curUserJobTitle = users[i].jobtitle;

       // access user picture url
       // contains the picture form the user profile service
       var curUserPicture = users[i].picture;

       // access sip address of user or group
       var curUserSip = users[i].sip;

       // access display name of user or group
      var curUserName = users[i].title;

    }
```

The id returned matches the id of the user information list that exists in every site collection. However, when you try to access this list directly you might have some trouble.
For performance reasons you should also consider to work with the already provided information listed above.

http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/handling-field-values-in-jslink-overrides

Comment: This returns `undefined`. :/

Comment: Becuase ``Author`` itself is an array, thats why I use ``Author[0]`` in the other answer

Comment: @DannyEngelman `Author` it's not an array, it's a string.

Comment: Check updated  answer

Comment: To me it's all `undefined`, because the `Author` field comes like string.

Comment: eVT, your script works perfect for me for the fields title, email, picture, department but does not work for jobtitle. I have a jobtitle in my UIL. Any ideas?